# The Placement.info in my module is not hiding the DateTime field

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

The documentation says (emphasis added):

> There are also special extensions for **certain fields** so that placement
>   can be targeted at specific field instances.

Does **certain fields** include the DateTime, Link, and Input fields?

I am trying to hide a DateTime field named Date when it is within a NewsItem content type. Here is my placement.info. **Importantly, this placement.info works from a theme but not from a module**.

```
<Match ContentType="NewsItem">

  <!--These ones do not work.-->
  <Place Fields_Input="-" />
  <Place Fields_DateTime="-" />
  <Place Fields_DateTime-Date="-" />
  <Place Fields_Link="-" />

  <!--These ones do work-->
  <Place Parts_Title="-" />
  <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-" />
  <Place Fields_Common_Text="-" />
  <Place Parts_Common_Body="-" />
  <Place Parts_Common_Body_Summary="-" />
  <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="-" />

</Match>
```

Here is Shape Tracing Model for one of the Fields:

[image: Fields_DateTime or Fields_DateTime-Date should work.]

Comment: Do you have something else in your placement overriding those ones you posted?

Comment: @Hazza Nope. I think, though, that it's impossible to override the placement.info that is in Orchard.Fields unless we do it from the Theme.

Comment: Agree with Hazza. What you posted should work. I've done it many times. Something else is taking precedence. Can you post your entire placement file?

Comment: I learned courtesy of Zoltan that the placement.info in Orchard.Fields probably has higher precedence than the one in my module. Apparently, I need to add a Dependencies field to my module.txt file, to make sure that my module's placement.info takes precedence over the Orchard.Fields placement.info file. Whether that's a good idea or not is a different question. See also http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/manifest-files

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue so I want to elevate this comment to a proper answer, since it seems to be the key:

> ...the `Placement.info` in *Orchard.Fields* probably has higher precedence than the one in [a custom] module... add a Dependencies field to [the custom module's] `Module.txt` file, to make sure that [the custom] module's `Placement.info` takes precedence over the *Orchard.Fields* `Placement.info` file.

If you are trying to override shapes for display inside the admin (e.g. in **SummaryAdmin** mode) from within a module, make sure your `Module.txt` lists dependencies for the modules that generate the shapes you are trying to override.

For example, if you want to override the `Fields_MediaLibraryPicker_SummaryAdmin` placement, your `Module.txt` should have at least:

```
Depedencies: Orchard.MediaLibrary
```

Credit to @Shaun Luttin and @Piedone